# Basic Ajax get request with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-mvc

am having issues with at very basic get request in my Spring MVC 3.2 project.

Heres my ajax request:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  function getApartmentList(){
      console.log("get");
      $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: '/getApartmentList',
          dataType: "json",
          contentType: "application/json",
          success: function(data){
              console.log("U are cool !!!");
             console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
          },
          error: function(xhr){
              console.log("error: " + xhr.status );
          }
      });
    }

  $("#testBtn").on("click", function(){
      getApartmentList();
  });


});
```

and here is the server method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getApartmentList", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public List<Apartment> getList(){

    Apartment ap = new Apartment();
    ap.setAdress("Norra Stationsgatan");
    ap.setHouseNumber(99);
    ap.setZip(11364);

    Apartment ap2 = new Apartment();
    ap2.setAdress("Birkagatan");
    ap2.setHouseNumber(32);
    ap2.setZip(11339);

    List<Apartment> list = new ArrayList<Apartment>();
    list.add(ap);
    list.add(ap2);

    return list;
}
```

why am i getting this error on browser console ?

```
GET http://localhost:8080/getApartmentList 404 (Not Found) jquery-2.1.0.js:8556
XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost:8080/getApartmentList".
```

so first the method i not found and then its found, what am i doing wrong.
you can se the whole project over at: 
https://github.com/gideono/Bokoll

Comment: Hi, what do you get when you visit http://localhost:8080/getApartmentList

Comment: Check the url is working or not. Once try to open the url ( http://localhost:8080/getApartmentList ) in browser

Comment: is this method inside of a controller? so, maybe the controller has a mapping, too. if it is so, your url will be something like: localhost:8080/<controllerMapping>/getApartmentList

Comment: THANKS !!!!! Manuel Richarz, added project main path and i worked. Use tomcat 8 on a previews project, where i did´t need the project path. Seems like Glass fish is different.

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning json,so remove `dataType:"json"`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      function getApartmentList(){
          console.log("get");
          $.ajax({
              type: 'GET',
              contentType: "application/json",
              url: '/getApartmentList',
              success: function(data){
                  console.log("U are cool !!!");
                 console.log(JSON.parse(data));
              },
              error: function(xhr){
                  console.log("error: " + xhr.status );
              }
          });
        }

  $("#testBtn").on("click", function(){
      getApartmentList();
  });


});
```